# Unable to instantiate a new object of a class

Tags: typescript, class, object, constructor

I'm having problems with this code in TypeScript

```
import Conf = require('conf');
const config = new Conf();
```

**Problem:** the expression is not constructable and the imported module has no construct signatures

This is weird because the module has a default export of a class called 'Conf' with a method called 'constructor'.

**Attempted solution**
I tried the following instead with reasoning to follow

```
const config = Conf;
config.constructor();
```

I thought maybe the issue was that 'Conf' exports the class itself and i need to assign that class to a variable and then call its methods directly like the above, but this seems a bit weird to me.

Why wouldn't the typical 'new' syntax work here?

**Sources**
Pkg for reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/conf

**Edit 1:**

The conf package gives the example as such:

```
const Conf = require('conf');

const config = new Conf();
```

Please note that in typescript, it's expected that the following import syntax is used in commonjs, so thats why i have used it:

```
import Conf = require('conf');
```

Src: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require

I dont think the import syntax is the issue here.

**Edit 2**

It was an import syntax issue lol. Thanks to Alex below.

Comment: The code example provided [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/conf) looks different from yours.

Comment: `const Conf = require('conf');
 
const config = new Conf();`

Comment: yes their version doesnt work in typescript, i get the error above. the import syntax is a bit different in typescript. i dont think its the issue from what i can see, as i can still access methods from the module if i do the second code snippet

Comment: Well, neither of your code samples matches the one they provided.  Are you sure you're using their code sample *exactly as written?*

Comment: the only difference in the first snippet is the import syntax. thats not the issue because i have access to the methods in the module if i do it the second way. i cant import with that exact syntax in typescript due to commonjs/es6 compiling issues (it throws errors)

Comment: @AlexWayne im following the commonjs import/export module syntax defined here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require

"When exporting a module using export =, TypeScript-specific import module = require("module") must be used to import the module."

Comment: Huh. I stand corrected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
import Conf from 'conf'
const config = new Conf()
```

The `import foo = require('foo')` syntax is sort of special. From the documentation you linked:

> They also support replacing the exports object with a custom single object. ***Default exports are meant to act as a replacement for this behavior; however, the two are incompatible.*** TypeScript supports export = to model the traditional CommonJS and AMD workflow.

And on when `import foo = require('foo')` is appropriate, it says:

> When exporting a module using export =, TypeScript-specific import module = require("module") must be used to import the module.

But if you look at [the code that exports the class you want](https://github.com/sindresorhus/conf/blob/master/source/index.ts#L577), you see this:

```
export default Conf;
```

Which is a very standard, very normal, typescript default export. And the way you import that in typescript is nearly always:

```
import Conf from 'conf'
```

[See it working here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-4xd6uf?file=index.ts)

Comment: You fixed it! It was an import issue lol

Im so confused over when or where to use the right import syntax. If u see below that export
"module.exports = Conf;
module.exports.default = Conf;"

it had support for commonjs import syntax, so theoretically my above one should still work?

Comment: I think so. But just always use `import Foo from 'foo'` or `import { SomethingInFoo } from 'foo'`, unless that doesn't work. This is what you want 99.99% of the time. Only if that fails should you start exploring other ways to import. I've been doing typescript for years and have never used `import/require` together in the same line like that. In fact, at first I was sure it was a syntax error.

Comment: so strange. i had to use that import/require one for another pkg because nothing else would work. does that mean the modules load async? is there a way to 'require' them to load synchronously?

Comment: The way to load modules async is [dynamic imports](https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports) and would be used for [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) in your bundler. It's great for only loading certain pages when you need to. But the vast majority of modules should be loaded synchronously.